# JS string to processed value

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I receive "Date.UTC(2013,1,26)" as a value from a ajax response.
I want to process it and get the value of it to a variable. How can I do it?

My JSON response is as follows:

```
{
"data": [
    [
        "Date.UTC(2013,1,26)",
        1
    ],
    [
        "Date.UTC(2013,1,27)",
        1
    ],
    [
        "Date.UTC(2013,1,27)",
        1
    ],
    [
        "Date.UTC(2013,1,28)",
        1
    ],
    [
        "Date.UTC(2013,2,20)",
        1
    ],
    [
        "Date.UTC(2013,2,20)",
        1
    ]
]
```

}

So in the program, I try to get this value and save the value as date

$.each(data, function(id,value) {

// I can get val[0] as Date.UTC(2013,1,26)

// I want to save the value as timestamp

});

Thanks
PSJ

Comment: Maybe you could post some code on what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with response

```
var response = {
    "data": [
        [
            "Date.UTC(2013,1,26)",
            1
        ]
        // here goes other values..
     ]
}
var date_string = response.data[0][0],
    arg = date_string
          .replace(/Date.UTC\((.*?)\)/, '$1')
          .split(',');

var timestamp = Date.UTC.apply( null , arg ) ,
    date      = new Date( timestamp  );
```

and print date result in console

```
console.log( date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() )
```

which print   `2013` `1` `26`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$.map(data, function(value) {
    return [Date.UTC.apply(null, value[0].replace(/[^(]+\(([^)]+)\)/g, '$1').split(',')),
            value[1]];
});
```